# Just In Time Debugger visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsjitdebugger

Hi i have build a windows form application at visual studio 2015 in my desktop that works just fine and i am using the `jit debugger` with the comand in visual studio `<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />`to get rid of some error messages.

The problem is that when i try to run my app at my laptop. It seems the app stops working when i press a certain button in my form and i have to disable `jit debugger` to work properly doing so i got errors messages that i want to get rid of.

Maybe it has something to do with OS of desktop and laptop ? In my desktop i have windows 7 and in my laptop i have windows 10.

Comment: what error message you get when you have jitDebugging as false?

Comment: You don't get rid of error messages by activating that switch. It will start the debugger. Do you have VS 2015 installed on the laptop?

Comment: @Vasanth when i turn to false i will get the same error messages that i used to get even without the command

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes my laptop has the visual studio 2015

Comment: check do you have this <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" /> in you config file

Comment: @Vasanth yeah that is all i am saying i have set jitDebugging to true. In desktop works with no problem. Setting it to laptop to true my app stops working for some reason